# Calculating RPN expression

Tags: python

I wrote a function to calculate RPN expression. First I defined help function `evaluate(a, b, op)` that takes two strings *a* and *b* that represent two integers and an operator *op* that is either '+' or '*'.

Example:

```
>>> evaluate('10', '5', '+')
'15'
 >>> evaluate('5', '3', '*')
'15'
```

Then I used that function in main function `rpn(s)` that takes a string that contains a valid RPN expression and returns the result.
The entire code goes like this:

```
def evaluate(a, b, op):
    return eval(a + op + b)


def rpn(s):
    s = tuple(s.split(' '))
    if len(s) == 3:
        return evaluate(s[0], s[1], s[2])
    else:
        return evaluate(rpn(' '.join(s[:(len(s) - 1) // 2])), rpn(' '.join(s[(len(s) - 1) // 2:-1])), s[-1])
```

The output should be:

```
>>> rpn('10 5 + 3 7 * +')
36
```

But when I run this code, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. 
Where is error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the values to the eval as string, try this:

```
def evaluate(a, b, op):
    return eval(str(a) + str(op) + str(b))
```